# Interesting puzzle in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hello studying Haskell I came up at an exercise at the web that it requested to create a list given an integer the way described below:

for example if integer was 3 then a list should be generated that it contains the following:

```
[[3],[1,2],[2,1],[1,1,1]]
```

note

```
3=3
1+2=3
2+1=3
1+1+1=3
```

if integer was 2 then it would be:

```
[[2],[1,1]]
```

I cannot think a way of implementing this, so can you provide me with any hints? I believe that I must use list comprehension but I cannot think anything further than this

Comment: It seems like you must create all permutations of sums that add up to the given value (excluding <= 0). Implementing it is tricky but not super difficult.

Comment: @DavidHaney Now you confused me further. To create a permutation I have to know a specific list and the take all the permutations. Here I dont have a specific list since I dont know how many lists I must produce. I mean in case of 3,4 list are generated while on case of 2,2  lists are generated. And there isn't a pattern..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always start with a type signature:

```
sums :: Int -> [[Int]]
```

Now, let's think about the recursion.

1. What is the base case? Can you think of a number for which the answer is trivial?
2. Let's say you've implemented your function and it works for all numbers under 10, so `sums 9` for example returns the right answer. How would you implement `sums 10`?

Don't bother yourself with implementation details (e.g. List comprehension vs. `filter` and `map`) until you've answered these questions.

And another tip: Haskell programmers love to show off and create tiny-pointfree functions, but don't let it confuse you. Getting things to work is the important thing. It's better to have a working yet somewhat "ugly" solution than to stare at the screen looking for an elegant one.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't you mean `Int -> [[Int]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit like partitioning a list. A bit of googling turns up this

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2011-April/006832.html

```
partitions [] = [[]]
partitions (x:xs) = [[x]:p | p <- partitions xs]
                 ++ [(x:ys):yss | (ys:yss) <- partitions xs]
```

which produces something like this

```
*Main> partitions "abc"
[["a","b","c"],["a","bc"],["ab","c"],["abc"]]
```

now all you have to do is get the length of the inner lists

```
map (map length) (partitions "abc")
[[1,1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3]]
```

you can also change partitions to give you the result directly

```
partitions' 0 = [[]]
partitions' n = [1:p | p <- partitions' (n-1)]
             ++ [(1+ys):yss | (ys:yss) <- partitions' (n-1)]
```

Comment: Hi. Your solution is fine, but the OP explicitly asked for hints, so maybe a full solution isn't a good answer in this case.

Comment: A nicer one-liner, IMO: `sums 0 = [[]]; sums x = [y : sum | y <- [1..x], sum <- sums $ x - y]`